# Google Tag Manager: GA Content Experiment code not firing on home page

Tags: google-tag-manager, content-experiments

I've created a Google Analytics Content Experiment in GA, copied the code, added it to my site's Google Tag Manager container, set it to trigger @

```
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/h2/
https://www.example.com/h3/
```

However, every time I load https://www.example.com in any browser, I stay there and am not redirected to a variant.

GA says the experiment code is detected at `/h2/` & `/h3/` but not `/`.

The Tag Manager code is installed in the same Wordpress theme that all of the above pages use.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Not sure if you know but Content Experiment is now Google Optimize.*

To debug this here is what I would do:

- **Make sure you follow the [official GTM instructions](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7164339?hl=en)** which include setting up `tag sequencing`
- **Enable the [GTM preview](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107056?hl=en)**
- **If the Optimize tag doesn't trigger**, GTM should tell you why (what trigger is failing, or what blocking trigger is being applied)
- **If the Optimize tag triggers BUT experiments don't**, I would clear browser cache to remove earlier Optimize persistence and make sure the experiment rules match the page conditions (eg URLs)
- **Another reason might be [Optimize timeout](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107056?hl=en)** whereby Optimize snippets take too long to load

> .async-hide { opacity: 0 !important} 
>       (function(a,s,y,n,c,h,i,d,e){s.className+=' '+y;h.start=1*new Date;
>       h.end=i=function(){s.className=s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?'+y),'')};
>       (a[n]=a[n]||[]).hide=h;setTimeout(function(){i();h.end=null},c);h.timeout=c;
>       })(window,document.documentElement,'async-hide','dataLayer',4000,
>       {'GTM-XXXXXX':true});